# jQuery - Method chaining not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm unable to get a set of chained methods to work.

The goal is to hide a dialog panel, which is working properly, and then change the classes for the `#nomoreIE` div.

I have tried many combinations to chain the `.addClass('masked').removeClass('poped')` methods without any indication of an error or success.

In addition, I would like to provide the ability to reopen the dialog if needed, which is the intention of the append() method.

```
$('.lt-ie9 #nomoreIE a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').live('click', function(e4){

    $('#nomoreIE').addClass('masked').removeClass('poped').animate({
    left: '-148px' }, {
        duration: '80',
        easing: 'easeInExpo'
    }).append('<div id="alert-ie"></div>');

    return false;

});
```

Any help appreciated

Thank you

here's the full list of code to answer 'DarkKing':

```
    // --------------- ienomore ------------------------------
// faire apparaitre au chargement
$('.lt-ie9 #nomoreIE').css({right: '-140px'}).delay(2000).animate({
       left: '0' }, {
                     duration: '80',
                      easing: 'easeOutBounce'
                     }).removeClass('masked').addClass('poped');


// gestion du close
$('.lt-ie9 #nomoreIE a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').live('click', function(e3){

    $('#nomoreIE').addClass('masked').removeClass('poped').animate({
       left: '-148px' }, {
                     duration: '80',
                      easing: 'easeInExpo'
                     }).append('<div id="alert-ie"></div>');

return false;

});

//gestion du open
$('.lt-ie9 #nomoreIE #alert-ie').live('click', function(e4){
    $('#nomoreIE').remove('#alert-ie').animate({
       left: '0' }, {
                     duration: '80',
                      easing: 'easeOutBounce'
                     }).removeClass('masked').addClass('poped');

});
```

Comment: Show us a demo using http://jsfiddle.net, or show your HTML markup. Are you sure you have an element named `#nomoreIE?` Are you sure the click handler is getting fired? jQuery doesn't error if a selector matches no elements, so thats often the problem when ***nothing happens***.

Comment: I tried to make a Jiddle.. putting the minimum to render what I'm talking about, but sorry does not works at all. Can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/elz64/UdmWx/

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this list:

- Your selection to sure the click handler is getting fired.
- Try use `$(this).parent()` instead of `$('#nomoreIE')`.
- Check `poped` class to sure existed.

This problem can be solved with these cases.

Comment: I edit my originalpost with the full code. the event is actualy fired because the dialog is animated to be hidden. I setup up this block in the code, then hide it immediatly touching its css 'right' property, and animating it to appears sliding from the left margin of the window. At this pointthe 'poped' class is actually added. Clicking the link cause the dialog to slide right but no action on class are still constated even doing a this.parent.

Answer (score 0):

I've uptaded the jiddle code to reflect the new approach.( http://jsfiddle.net/elz64/UdmWx/2/)
However nothing is functionnal in Jiddle.

I removed the conditional comments and css targeting for ".lt-ie9" to deal with Firebug in FF.

The previous code WAS working in FF but not in IE and still I don't know why.

**One sure thing : the F12 console is not refreshed by jQuery dom manipulation(!?), so it does not reflects in real time the actions.**

I guess there was some specific IE issue but also some working stuff (like the class manipulation) not visible cause of the console which was not actualized !

As there were some glitch for the appended div (a small 6x6 icon) I managed to change the positioning and so on.
Now the new code is ok in IE too.